# How to combine two line charts with (Numbers/Percentage) for y axis and date for x axis and set scaling with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, linechart

I have this data frame which contains date column, amount column and percentage value column. Want to draw a graph which has date column for x axis, amount column for y axis in left and percentage column for y axis on the right.

I could build up below code to draw two graphs and join into one. But, the second y axis don't appear as expected. And the lines related to percentage values are not displayed. I think that is due to scaling issue. Some help would be highly appreciated, as I am unable to figure out why the second y axis is not displayed, and the meaning of below properties.

```
updating_file = "D:\\Testing\\Pivot.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(filename=updating_file, data_only=True)
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
columns = next(sheet.values)[0:]
current_sheet_df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values, columns=columns)

c1 = LineChart()
c1.title = None
c1.y_axis.title = None

c1.y_axis.crossAx = 500
c1.x_axis = DateAxis(crossAx=100)
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm'
c1.x_axis.lblAlgn = 'l'
c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"
c1.x_axis.title = "Date"

data1 = Reference(sheet, min_col=10, min_row=3, max_row=current_sheet_df.shape[0]+2)
data2 = Reference(sheet, min_col=14, min_row=3, max_row=current_sheet_df.shape[0]+2)
c1.add_data(data1, titles_from_data=True)
c1.add_data(data2, titles_from_data=True)

dates = Reference(sheet, min_col=9, min_row=4, max_row=current_sheet_df.shape[0]+2)
c1.set_categories(dates)

# Create a second chart
c2 = LineChart()
v2 = Reference(sheet, min_col=11, max_col=13, min_row=3, max_row=current_sheet_df.shape[0]+2)
c2.add_data(v2, titles_from_data=True)
c2.set_categories(dates)
# c2.y_axis.axId = 200
c2.y_axis.title = None

c2.x_axis = DateAxis(crossAx=100)
c2.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm'
c2.x_axis.lblAlgn = 'l'
c2.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"
c2.x_axis.title = "Date"
c2.y_axis.majorGridlines = None
c1.y_axis.majorGridlines = None


# Display y-axis of the second chart on the right by setting it to cross the x-axis at its maximum
c1.y_axis.crosses = "min"
c2.y_axis.crosses = "max"
c1 += c2

c1.legend.position = 't'

# # Style the lines
s1 = c1.series[0]
s1.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "BDCDCD" # Marker outline

sheet.add_chart(c1, "Q20")

wb.save(filename=updating_file)
```

The graph drawn with above code is as follows;

[image]

Want to draw something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

based on the sample code at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/charts/secondary.html
and some try I found there has to be an axis ID definition to separate 2 axes from each other

```
c2.y_axis.axId = 200
c1.y_axis.crosses = "max"
c1 += c2
```